# ¿Cómo cargar un DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC5, estoy tratando de cargar un dropdownlist con datos.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Listar()
    {
        var proveedor = SdProveedor.ListaTipoDocumentoIdentidad();
        ViewBag.ListaProveedores = new SelectList(proveedor, "Id", "Descripcion");
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Me da error: No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` con la clave `myDropDown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder obtener la lista de una base de datos (con datos de Id y Descripción) y mostrarla en un `DropDownList`, te recomiendo utilizar la siguiente funcionalidad que por alguna razón, el `DropDownList` trabaja perfectamente con `List<SelectListItem>`:

Código del `Controller`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var proveedor = SdProveedor.ListaTipoDocumentoIdentidad();
    ViewBag.ListaProveedores = ListaProveedores.Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.Id.ToString(), Text = p.Descripcion }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
    return View();
}
```

Código en el `View`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaProveedores, "Seleccione un Proveedor", new { @class = "form-control small" })
```

Comment: Este método lo quiero usar en la vista del Create donde necesito mostrar una lista de datos en un DropDownList, en ese caso es la misma técnica que estas usando en la View?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este método para cargar DropDownList:

***ViewModel:***

```
public class GroupViewModel
{  
    //... tus otras propiedades 

    public int LabId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Labs { get; set; }       
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Cargar DropDownList obligar valores
    var model = new GroupViewModel
    {
        // Ejempleo I : Cargar desde una lista estática
        var model = new GroupViewModel();
        model.Labs = new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="One" },
            new SelectListItem { Value ="2", Text="Two" }
        };
        //

        //Ejempleo II : Cargar desde una base de datos   
        Labs = repository.Labs.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
    return PartialView("Create", model);
}
```

***View:***

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LabId, new SelectList(Model.Labs, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
```

Saludos...