# Seleccionar item en DropDownList - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo problemas para recuperar la informacion ya cargada en un DropDownList

tengo una vista con un foreach del modelo

```
    @foreach (sfi_1.Models.SFI_IncentivoDet itemInc in incentivos)
```

tengo un DropDownList

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s=> s.Tipo_Incentivo, listaTiposIncentivos, itemInc.Tipo_Incentivo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Lo cargo desde la base de datos con una lista que tiene:

```
    Text = c.Descrip_Atributo.ToString(),
    Value = c.ID_Atributo.ToString()
```

El problema que tengo es que si no le pongo el parametro "itemInc.Tipo_Incentivo" no me muestra el valor que tiene el item del foreach, si lo pongo me muestra el codigo y yo necesito la descripción.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo cargar un DropDownList?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44739/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-un-dropdownlist)

Comment: No, quiero saber como setear el valor seleccionado de una lista que tiene text y value