# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

Lo que sucede es que genere un `dropdowlist` con una consulta a sql en el metodo GET que funciona bien, Esto se complementa con otros parametros que lo que me hacen es ejecutar un sp para una creacion pero me sale el error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No hay ningún elemento ViewData de
>   tipo 'IEnumerable' con la clave 'CAMPANIA'.'

luego de ejecutar el boton si yo reviso los datos la ejecucion del sp si se realizo pero el error persiste

-Esta es la vista y donde se genera el error

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CAMPANIA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CAMPANIA", lista, "Seleccione", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>"
```

El controlador es

```
public ActionResult CrearCli()
        {
            using (var db = new HermesEntities())

            {
                try
                {
                    List<CreacionClienteVidaSp> lst = null;

                    lst = (from d in db.TblCampania
                           where d.Estado == "A-A5"
                           select new CreacionClienteVidaSp

                           {
                               CAMPANIA = d.Campania

                           }).ToList();



                    List<SelectListItem> items2 = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
                    {
                        return new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = d.CAMPANIA.ToString(),
                            Value = d.CAMPANIA.ToString(),
                            Selected = false
                        };
                    });


                    ViewBag.items2 = items2;


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {


                }
                    return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CrearCli(CreaClienteSp model)

        {

            using (var db = new HermesEntities())

            {
                CreaClienteSp cca = new CreaClienteSp();

                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec SP_CREACION_CLIENTE_AUTOS_V5 @CAMPANIA, @CONSULTADOCUMENTO, @CONSULTANOMBRES, @CONSULTACELULAR, @CONSULTAPLACA, @OBSERVACION, @AGENTE",
                    new SqlParameter("@CAMPANIA", cca.CAMPANIA = model.CAMPANIA),
                    new SqlParameter("@CONSULTADOCUMENTO", cca.CONSULTADOCUMENTO = model.CONSULTADOCUMENTO),
                    new SqlParameter("@CONSULTANOMBRES", cca.CONSULTANOMBRES = model.CONSULTANOMBRES),
                    new SqlParameter("@CONSULTACELULAR", cca.CONSULTACELULAR = model.CONSULTACELULAR),
                    new SqlParameter("@CONSULTAPLACA", cca.CONSULTAPLACA = model.CONSULTAPLACA),
                    new SqlParameter("@OBSERVACION", cca.OBSERVACION = model.OBSERVACION),
                    new SqlParameter("@AGENTE", cca.AGENTE = model.AGENTE)

                    );



            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
```

El modelo del dropdownlist

```
namespace Grabaciones.Models.Dropdowlnist
{
    public class ListadoCampanias
    {
        public string CAMPANIA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Y el modelo para el resto de la vista

```
namespace Grabaciones.Models
{
    public partial class CreaClienteSp
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Campaña")]
        public string CAMPANIA { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Documento")]
        public string CONSULTADOCUMENTO { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombres")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-z A-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se aceptan letras en el campo Nombre.")]
        public string CONSULTANOMBRES { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Celular")]
        public string CONSULTACELULAR { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Placa")]
        public string CONSULTAPLACA { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Observacion")]
        public string OBSERVACION { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Codigo de Agente")]
        public string AGENTE { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice ese error es que no tienes ningún listado con nombre `CAMPANIA`.

El fallo te lo está dando en:

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CAMPANIA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

Ya que aquí estas queriendo obtener un listado de campañas, pero en tu modelo no has declarado ningún listado, tan solo has denominado un string, para solucionarlo puedes tratar de cambiar el modelo a:

```
public class ListadoCampanias
    {        
        //Generas un listado de CAMPANIAS    
        public List<CreaClienteSp> CAMPANIA { get; set; }
    }
```

No comprendo bien tu controlador ya que no tengo un nivel muy alto, pero por lo que puedo observar es que retornas un `view()` en vez de un `view(tuModelo)`, no se si eso causa que no recibas ningún dato en tu modelo de la vista.

Te dejo un enlace a [este fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sPDf59) que puede venirte bien, para comprender el funcionamiento de un dropdownlist y [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44755/101499) que te puede ser de ayuda.