# Llenado de un SelectListItem

Tags: c#

quisiera una ayuda con el llenado de un SelectListItem.
Tengo el controlador donde creo mi SelectListItem, y como pueden ver se llena a través de una función que se encuentra en otra clase:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es esta función:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me comentan que si puedo mejorar el codigo, ya que esta función se encuentra en la capa de negocio, y me dicen que es una mala practica de programación utilizar componentes web en la capa de negocio, alguien me podría ayudar a como mejorar esta función sin utilizar los componentes web.?

Comment: Antes que te den negativos, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo cargar un DropDownList?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44739/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-un-dropdownlist)